# What is the root cause for NHibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: asp.net, .net, nhibernate

I am supporting a project which is developed through NHibernate framework. Recently *(only occasionally)*, I am  getting this error `NHibernate.LazyInitializationException` only on a particular class . In my case only on the user case. My full exception is

> NHibernate.LazyInitializationException [(null)] - Initializing[*******.Domain.EpmsUser#129]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session

I am well aware that the Lazy load in the framework will update data randomly. I am quiet not sure why my session is expiring only when I access this Class.

Please share what are the root cause for this issue and if possible can provide few tips/solution to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in a nutshell:

> Web applications are splited into pieces *(presenter/controller action, view rendering)*, which usually have ***lifetime*** related to the web `Request`. During that `Request`, we can *load* or *persist* our data... almost anytime.
>   And that means that we should keep NHibernate `ISession` ***lifetime*** related to that `Request` ***lifetime***

See more here:

#### [Effective NHibernate Session management for web apps](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2011/03/02/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.html)

Few things to check

- find out where is your session init and where is closed
- MVC has two mayor phases - 1) controller action 2) view rendering - if we do not work with DTO - objects dependent on session will require to keep it open until view is completely rendered
- check some AOP stuff (too soon, or too late) working with some "loaded" objects, after or before session is closed